# Create a client to send something using java

Tags: java, websocket, client

I am trying to create a client to send an object named "Post" using java.Here is my code

```js
package net;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import base.Post;

public class BlogClient {

 public static final String IP = "127.0.0.1";
 public static final int port = 3021;

 public static String host = "";


 
 public static void main(String[] args){
  try{
   InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1");
   host = addr.getHostName();
  }catch(UnknownHostException e){
   System.out.println("Shot");
   System.exit(1);
  }
  try(Socket socket =new Socket(host, port);//open a socket 
   PrintWriter out =new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(),true); //send to the server
   BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));//echo from the server
   BufferedReader stdIn=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))//client input 
   ){
    String userInput;
    //while( (userInput=stdIn.readLine()) != null ){ 
    while( (userInput=stdIn.readLine()) != null ){
     
     Post p = new Post(userInput);
     out.println(p.toString());
     out.flush();//needed, since the buffered may not be full.
     System.out.println("echo:"+in.readLine());
    }
     
  }catch(UnknownHostException e){  
   System.err.println("Don't know about host"+ IP);   
   System.exit(1); 
  }catch(IOException e){
   System.err.println("Couldnt get I/O for the connection to "+IP);  
   System.exit(1);
  }
 }
}
```

While executing, the console says: Couldnt get I/O for the connection to 127.0.0.1.

Could someone tell my why will throw this exception?

(PS:127.0.0.1 is the LAN ip of my school)

Comment: actually `127.0.0.1` should be your local machine... did you modified `hosts` file?

Comment: Try printing `e.getMessage()` in the catch block, it might shed some light on the nature of the IOException

Answer (score 0):

127.0.0.1 is the localhost. It can be change by modifying hosts file. But in your case we can do one thing, we can check whether there is a code issue or network issue.

**By Using Windows cmd Prompt**

```
    telnet 127.0.0.1 3021 // 3021 is the port no.
```

if blanks screen comes it means, network connection established , if you get some exception, it means there is a network issue. It can be firewall which is preventing the request.